# newline markup in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
   <script>
        $('#textarea_').on('keyup', function () {
            var textareaContentWithJquery = $('#textarea_').val();
            var textareaContentWithJavascript = document.getElementById('textarea_').value;
        });
    </script>

        <textarea cols="20" id="textarea_" name="textarea_" rows="2">
Some text in textarea here is created without pressing enter, 
just plain text. But how can i get the position 
of  newline markup from textarea so that i can put <br> there? 
        </textarea>
```

i get value from textarea  like that(plain text);
Some text in textarea here is created without pressing enter, just plain text. But how can i get the position of  newline markup from textarea so that i can put `<br>` there?

If I were to press enter in textarea and pass to new line then it would be easy because there would be an `\n` at the place where I press enter but when I just add text and let the textarea wrap the text to a new line then I have no `\n` there in the text.

I need it to be like this (not plain text) ;

```
Some text in textarea here is created without pressing enter,\n
just plain text. But how can i get the position\n
of  newline markup from textarea so that i can put <br> there?\n

So i would easily replace \n with <br> 
Some text in textarea here is created without pressing enter,<br> 
just plain text. But how can i get the position<br> 
of  newline markup from textarea so that i can put <br> there? <br>
```

textareaContentWithJquery and textareaContentWithJavascript gives the same result i mean without `\n` markup. So they are useless.

Comment: Are you using PHP for displaying Data in the Textarea and it has those Html entities ?

Comment: your first issue is that a new line is represented as `\n` not `/n`

Comment: `$('textarea').val().match(/\n/g)`  ???

Comment: @SpYk3HH but i can not get \n there so how can i match??

Comment: @SpYk3HH hmm anyway i will give it a try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a newline character after every 200 characters with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321500/how-to-insert-a-newline-character-after-every-200-characters-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `&#013;` for the new line, and then search for `\n` and replace with `<br>`.

```
 <textarea cols="20" id="textarea_" name="textarea_" rows="12" cols="150">
    Some text in textarea here is created without pressing enter, just plain text. 
    But how can i get the position of newline markup from textarea so that i can put <br>&#013; there? 
 </textarea>

$('#textarea_').on('keyup', function () {
   var textareaContentWithJquery = $('#textarea_').val();                  
   console.log(textareaContentWithJquery.replace(/\n/g, "<br>"));
});
```

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/nobrien/pen/QNmOpv

Comment: nope this doesn't work. Because there is no \n in textareaContentWithJquery.

Comment: for instance in the first line type "sometext" and then add one space and then keep adding text and let it pass new line and then check it again because there would be no <br> added(except at the very end of text).

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand what you are saying, or else I don't understand what you are wanting it to do.  My codepen is adding br tags anywhere there is a linebreak added before hand or typed.  I updated the pen to output the results to the screen, as well as the console.

Comment: make cols=20 and then try again...it would be like "Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text <br>" which i can not get line break except at the end of text.

Comment: Well if you are typing manually, you would just type the return key, not type the encoded variable.  Hitting the return key is creating a br tag when I do it.

Comment: but i can not tell user to do so anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand what you are actually trying to do then.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#textarea_').on('keyup', function () {
   var textareaContentWithJquery = $('#textarea_').val();                  
   console.log(textareaContentWithJquery.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />'));
});
```